# Spark DataFrame with current date + 10

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have some sales data and created DataFrame using a CSV file. In this DataFrame I need to add two additional columns `process_date` and `next_processing_date`. So written like this:

```
baseData.withColumn("Return_Grace_period", current_date()).withColumn("Next_processing_date", current_date() + 10).show()
```

Here `current_date()+10` is causing an issue. In oracle we can use 10 for getting the next date. How can I do so in Spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`date_add`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#date_add-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-int-) function to add a number of days to a date:

```
baseData.withColumn("Next_processing_date", date_add(current_date(), 10))
```

To instead subtract a number of days, you can use the matching `date_sub` function.

Comment: thanks but scala sql notation, it is causing the issue. So written like this   baseData.select($"Sales",$"current_date".as("processing_date"),$"date_add(current_date(),2))".as("grace_period")).show()

Comment: @LearnHadoop: `date_add` is not a column so you can't use the `$` notation here. You can write it as: `baseData.select($"Sales", current_date().as("processing_date"), date_add(current_date(), 2)).as("grace_period")).show()`.

Comment: thanks a lot sir.. appreciated your help